# Prolog Recursion Length Count

Tags: recursion, prolog

This might be a simple / basic problem but I am having troubles grasping the logic.

I want to calculate the length of the list, using recursion.
Imagine having a list [a,b,c,d] for this problem.

We have a basic clause, and a recursive clause as can be seen below.
The basic clause always deals with the most basic problem, in this case an empty list. The recursive clause tries to solve the problem for size N-1 of the list.

```
listLength([],0).

listLength([Head|Tail], Count):-
    listLength(Tail, PartialCount),
    Count is PartialCount+1.
```

Now, my question is the following:

Let's look at this piece of code:

```
listLength(Tail, PartialCount)
```

The program will keep on running until the Tail is empty, which will then pass to `listLength([],0).`
for which PartialCount becomes equal to 0.
Then, the program continues to `Count is PartialCount+1.` and Count becomes equal to 1.

Then the program starts backtracking to the other "unsolved" lengths.
First it starts with [d], since this was the last element that it tried to solve, now **PartialCount becomes 1**, and this is what I don't understand.
How come PartialCount suddenly becomes "1", which makes Count equal to 2 afterwards, since in the program, there is no indiciation of re-defining the PartialCount.

The program also backtracks to [c,d], which makes Partial Count equal to 2, and so forth.

Can someone explain how this happens? As far as I know, PartialCount is set to "0" in the `listLength([],0]` example, but I don't know how its value gets updated?
I see that`Count` gets updated, but not `PartialCount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a separate `PartialCount` in each recursive call. It's like local variables versus global. Local variable masks global variable with the same name. The local variable in the deepest nesting masks the ones outside it.

ADDITION: Here is what happens:

```
Call [a,b,c,d]
  Call [b,c,d]
    Call [c,d]
      Call [d]
        Call []
        Success (first clause): Count = 0, no ParticalCount
      Success (2nd clause): PartialCount = 0, Count = 1
    Success (2nd clause): PartialCount = 1, Count = 2
  Success (2nd clause): PartialCount = 2, Count = 3
Success (2nd clause): PartialCount = 3, Count = 4
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, when backtracking it goes back to listLength(Tail, PartialCount), right? Or does it go back all the way up to listLength([Head|Tail], Count)

Comment: Actually there is no backtracking at all. The code is deterministic. Only one of the clauses can match, either empty list or non-empty list in parameter one. Will add explanation in answer.

Comment: I really try to grasp it, but I still dont understand how "PartialCount" gets updated constantly. I don't see any value added to PartialCount.

Comment: They key is the recusive call (`listLength(Tail, PartialCount)`). The value of `Count` on the next level (down) becomes `PartialCount` on the current level.